# android 5.1.1 wont install apps

Tags: root-access

I have a Alcatel onetouch model 50540 running android 5.1.1 as in the title. it is rooted and began uninstalling pre-installed bloatware on my device. I do not have a complete list of uninstalled apps because I had only kept track after the first few, but ill list the ones I do know about

- Download Manager
- Downloads
- Talkback
- Hangouts
- Cricket Wi-Fi Manager
- Camera
- Email
- Onetouch Launcher

That is the essence of what I did. I do have an edited hosts file as a makeshift adblock.

Play store gives me an error code 0 to which I removed app data and tried again, same problem.

I have tried installing local apps which brings up an "app not installed" box.

Lastly I have tried do directly extract the app into /data/app and rebooting which didn't work.

Comment: @Char-kun Did you remove any kind of `Package Installer`, by the way?

Comment: No the package installer app is still there. @Death Mask Salesman

Answer (score -2):

I figured it out, I uninstalled Google talk which led to all the issues.